# dot (.) is being retrieved as © from MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, image

I have stored the path of the Image in the MYSQL table.Now when I try to retrieve the path, all the path is retrieved correctly except that dot(.) of .jpg is retrieved as ©jpg and thus there comes an exception that no such file exists.

```
string fileName =Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[rowIndex]["photo"]);    //File name with Exstension and Path
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();    //BitmapImage for showing in the image control
        img.BeginInit();
        img.UriSource = new Uri(fileName);
        img.EndInit();
        imgPic.Source = img;
```

[Screen shot of my problem window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Erd.png)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the . is in the database, rather than the ©?

Comment: Could you add a tag for the used programming language?

Comment: Does the conversion happen before or after the `Convert.ToString()` function?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. I had actually changed the collation of that particular column from ascii_general_ci to armscii8_general_ci